# Angular error when trying to retrieve JSON

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm trying to retrieve a simple JSON list and inject it into a dropdown list.

However, I'm getting an error from the following JS.

```
var rac  =  angular.module('rac', ['angular.filter']);

rac.controller('prodCtrl', function($scope, $http, $sce, $filter){
  var dataURL = 
$sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5b1ef454310000fa163ffa45');
  $http({
    method: 'JSONP',
    url: dataURL
  }).then(function ($scope, response) {
    $scope.products.data = response;
    console.log($scope.products);
  }, function (response) {
    console.log("Mr. Data. Report! " + response);
  });   
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
  <h1>Leonard Zakoor - Rolled Alloys </h1>
  <div ng-controller="prodCtrl">
    <h3>Please choose a product</h3>
    <select>
      <option ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.name}}</option>
    </select>


  </div>

</div>
```

The error I'm getting is: 
TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined

On line 9

```
$scope.products.data = response;
```

Comment: you have to first define $scope.products even if it is just `$scope.products = {};`

Comment: Thanks! Been looking at this too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define **`$scope.products = [];`**

and then ng-repeat over,

```
 <option ng-repeat="product in products">{{product.name}}</option>
```

**EDIT:**
I have made few changes on the request as follows,

```
rac.controller('prodCtrl', function($scope, $http, $sce, $filter) {
  $http.jsonp($sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://www.mocky.io/v2/5b1ef454310000fa163ffa45"), {
      jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.products = data.data.products;
      },
      function(error) {}
    );
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/RAkNHVvODDjJWspd572u)**

Comment: So I did try that, but nothing is showing up. Ultimately, I want something like this: http://embed.plnkr.co/R6u0QYAyKj3IvRGEtWp8

Comment: also you need to do this $scope.products= response.data;

Comment: That gives me an error: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: Let me build a sample

Comment: That did it! Thanks

Comment: Great glad to help

Comment: I should start leaving my comments as answers more often and reap the sweet karma :D

Comment: if you closely look, your ocmment is not the answer

Comment: Actually it is. You define $scope.products just as I said. It solves the error he asked about. I wasn't trying to argue about it, just thought it was funny.

Comment: Try to understand the answer, i am not arguing too! but it was actually a problem with the request itself